# Cuda: Changing grid dimension during execution

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm having trouble trying to define clearly the structure of my CUDA code. My code is divided into two phases: First, I need to run M * N operations, and the results of these is used in other N operations. To take advantage of CUDA, I wonder if you can have two levels of parallelism. First, a instrucion with dimGrid (N * M / dimBlock.x, N * M / dimBlock.y) and then another with dimGrid (N / dimBlock.x, N / dimBlock.y).

Comment: If by "instruction" you mean "kernel launch", then you can run the same kernel with different blocks per grid and threads per block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can launch kernels that have different grid sizes/configurations on the GPU.  This is true whether you are launching the same kernel:

```
dim3 dimBlock(block_x, block_y);
dim3 dimGrid1(N*M/dimBlock.x, N*M/dimBlock.y);
mykernel<<<dimGrid1, dimBlock>>>(...);
dim3 dimGrid2(N/dimBlock.x, N/dimBlock.y);
mykernel<<<dimGrid2, dimBlock>>>(...);
```

or different kernels:

```
dim3 dimBlock(block_x, block_y);
dim3 dimGrid1(N*M/dimBlock.x, N*M/dimBlock.y);
mykernel1<<<dimGrid1, dimBlock>>>(...);
dim3 dimGrid2(N/dimBlock.x, N/dimBlock.y);
mykernel2<<<dimGrid2, dimBlock>>>(...);
```

There is also something called [CUDA dynamic parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Dynamic_Parallelism_Programming_Guide.pdf) which allows you to do the following, but it requires a GPU of compute capability 3.5:

```
__global__ void kernel2(...){
...
}

__global__ void kernel1(...){
...
dim3 dimBlock(block_x, block_y);
dim3 dimGrid(N/dimBlock.x, N/dimBlock.y);
kernel2<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(...);
...
}
```

and with dynamic parallelism it's even possible to call the same kernel recursively:

```
__global__ void kernel1(...){
...
dim3 dimBlock(block_x, block_y);
dim3 dimGrid(N/dimBlock.x, N/dimBlock.y);
kernel1<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(...);
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I use a TESLA C2075, so I can not currently use dynamic parallelism.